# C++ coroutines and const reference parameters

Tags: c++, c++20, temporary-objects, c++-coroutine

From *Note 3* in https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#13

> [Note 3: If a coroutine has a parameter passed by reference, resuming the coroutine after the lifetime of the entity referred to by that parameter has ended is likely to result in undefined behavior. — end note]

It is very clear that taking a parameter by reference in a coroutine may result in undefined behavior if a careless caller doesn't make sure the provided argument outlives the coroutine object.

But what about a const reference parameter initialized with a temporary? It would make sense to me if the standard guaranteed that the lifetime of the parameter is extended by the local reference but I can't find anything about it.

Is this defined behavior (assuming coro() uses obj after the first suspension) and if so what is it?

```
task<void> coro(const Obj& obj);

...

auto tsk = coro(Obj{});
co_await tsk;
```

It seems to me that if this is not permitted, const references can simply not be used as coroutine parameters for the risk of someone passing a temporary and assuming ordinary function behavior.

Comment: `const&` can be safe for things like: `generator<T> coro(const Obj& obj)` `for (const T& x : coro(Obj{}))`. Or for simply `auto x = co_await coro(Obj{});` (any place where the return type of the coroutine is itself a temporary)

Comment: @Artyer What do you mean? Why does the return type matters?

Comment: I meant the returned object

Answer (score 5):

> It is very clear that taking a parameter by reference in a coroutine may result in undefined behavior if a careless caller doesn't make sure the provided argument outlives the coroutine object.
>
> But what about a const reference parameter initialized with a temporary?

That's the *definition* of "a careless caller" who "doesn't make sure the provided argument outlives the coroutine object". There are no special provisions in this case. The lifetime of a temporary used as a function argument is extended to that of the full expression containing the function call. That function call being a coroutine doesn't change this.

Remember: being a coroutine is an implementation detail of the function. The caller (the one with the temporary) does not know if a function is a coroutine or not. So not only are there no special provisions, there *cannot* be special provisions.

> It seems to me that if this is not permitted, const references can simply not be used as coroutine parameters for the risk of someone passing a temporary and assuming ordinary function behavior.

The general way C++ is designed assumes that the user knows what they're doing. The language frequently refrains from stopping you from doing something dangerous so long as it is possible to use that thing in a non-dangerous way.

That having been said, the coroutine function itself can simply internally copy any such parameters to its stack if they want. The coroutine can be set to not initially suspend, which guarantees that it will execute up to the first explicit suspension point. At which point, they can do whatever they want to make this usage safe. Maybe the function never uses the parameter after the first suspension point. Maybe something else.

So your example *may* have UB or may not, depending on what happens inside the coroutine.

Comment: [@Nicol Bolas] What my question meant was, in a regular function, a const reference parameter will extend the life of a temporary (as would a local const reference), would it make sense to do the same with a coroutine parameter?

Comment: Are coroutines actually allowed to copy parameters like you mention? Wouldn't that create issues when you actually require the coroutine to work on the exact entity you passed in? Or what about types that cannot be copied?

Comment: @imreal: The lifetime extension of a temporary used as a function argument lasts until the end of the expression that the function call is used within. For a normal function, that would mean that the function has ended. But not for a coroutine, as they can suspend without being finished using those parameters.

Comment: @Juliean: "*Wouldn't that create issues when you actually require the coroutine to work on the exact entity you passed in?*" Who is "you" in this instance? A function dictates how it uses its parameters, not the caller. Coroutines don't change this. "*Or what about types that cannot be copied?*" Then the writer of the coroutine would get a compile error when they try to copy it. Or if it's a template function, the coroutine would have been constrained on the parameter being copyable, so the caller will get the error when they violate that constraint.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, you meant actually the writer of the function, not the compiler. I was reading it as in, the implementation of the coroutine in the compiler/library. Makes sense that way.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to add anything to @NicolBolas answer.

However, a short advice how to prevent from such bugs like referring to dangling reference inside coroutine.

Use `std::reference_wrapper<const T>` to prevent accidental use of references to temporary if you need to have const reference - or just pass by value if you need only value.

```
#include <functional>

task<> foo(const int& a)
{
   co_return;
}

task<> foo_no_temp(std::reference_wrapper<const int> a)
{
   co_return;
}

int main() {
    auto c1 = foo(1);
    // auto c2 = foo_no_temp(1); // does not compile
    const int a = 1;
    auto c3 = foo_no_temp(a);
}
```